# Como mostrar os dados do GetAll que realizei em uma tabela HTML? MVC C# HTML

Tags: c#, html, mvc, lista

Estou realizando um simples site em mvc, pela faculdade. Tenho que realizar um crud. Criei um metodo getall que lista todos os clientes ja existentes em uma lista.

Como posso passo a mesma para a view? Tentei a linha abaixo porém não consigo utilizar..

```
@model List<cliente>
```

> Model Cliente com o metódo get all

```
public List<Cliente> getall()
    {
        string StringDeConexao = @"CONNECTION";
        List<Cliente> clientes = new List<Cliente>(); //instancia lista

        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(StringDeConexao))
        {
            {
                cn.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from cliente", cn);

                var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read()) 
                {
                    Cliente cliente = new Cliente();

                    cliente.ID = (int)dr["ID"];
                    cliente.Nome = (string)dr["Nome"];
                    cliente.Email = (string)dr["Email"];
                    cliente.Tel = (string)dr["Tel"];
                    cliente.Cidade = (string)dr["Cidade"];
                    cliente.Documento = (string)dr["Documento"];
                    cliente.Data = (DateTime)dr["Data"];

                    clientes.Add(cliente); 
                }
            }

            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                cn.Close();
            }
            return clientes;
        }
    }
```

> Controller Cliente

```
public ActionResult List(Cliente cliente)
    {
        cliente.getall();
        return View(cliente);
    }
```

> View Cliente

```
div class="table">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ID</td>
                            <td>Nome</td>
                            <td>E-mail</td>
                            <td>Tel</td>
                            <td>Cidade</td>
                            <td>Documento</td>
                            <td>Data</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>
```

Como exibir o list na view sem entity framework?

Comment: Mas não consegue porquê? Dá erro?

Comment: Quero saber como jogar ali nos <td></td> vazios. Tentei por lá em cima

    @model List<Cliente>

Mas não funciona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. Então o que tem de fazer é fazer um foreach e criar um  para cada coluna:

```
@foreach (var clientes in Model) {
   <td>
    clientes.Nome
   </td>   
   <td>
    clientes.Email
   </td>   
......
}
```

Comment: Mas a linha "@model List<Cliente>" não funciona, esse foreach é baseado nela não é?

Comment: Sim. Mas, novamente, tem de ser mais detalhado. "Não funciona" porque? Dá erro? Normalmente eu coloco no "@"model um IEnumerable: "@"model IEnumerable<cliente>

Comment: É exatamente essa linha que não estou conseguindo definir corretamente. Coloquei "@" model List<Cliente> ; "@" model IEnumerable<Cliente> ; E não funciona. Essa linha que falta.

Comment: Eu vou perguntar mais uma vez: Não funciona, porquê? Qual é o erro que dá?

Comment: Consegui utilizar desta forma: "@"model List<Projeto.Models.Cliente>

Depois no for each: "@"foreach (Projeto.Models.Cliente cliente in Model), o erro dava que vinha um objeto cliente enquanto esperava uma lista do mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, brow!

Pelo que eu vi em seu código, você está retornando para a view o mesmo cliente que está recebendo como parâmetro na ActionResult List.

Alterar para:

```
public ActionResult List(Cliente cliente)
{
    var clientes = cliente.getall();
    return View(clientes);
}
```

Fazendo essa alteração, se a sua view estiver tipada com

```
@model SeuNameSpace.Cliente
```

Precisa alterar para

```
@model IEnumerable<SeuNameSpace.Cliente>
```

Ai sim, basta fazer a leitura com um foreach na View:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>Nome</td>
      <td>Email</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      @foreach(var cliente in Model)
      {
        <td>@cliente.Nome</td>
        <td>@cliente.Email</td>
      }
   </tr>
</table>
```